# Running query against SQL Server with FreeTDS's bsqldb returns blank output

Tags: sql-server-2008, freetds

Here is the query I ran

```
select CAST(PageGuid as varchar(max)) + ',' + CAST(TenantGuid as varchar(max)) + '/' + CAST(OriginalFileGuid as varchar(max)) 
from Pages
```

This worked with tsql but when run with bsqldb I get empty lines instead of results.

I confirmed that bsqldb works by running other simple queries. So why is this one not working?

Here is the verbose output

```
bsqldb:163: Verbose operation enabled
bsqldb:212: Query:
    select CAST(PageGuid as varchar(max)) + ',' + CAST(TenantGuid as  varchar(max)) + '/' + CAST(OriginalFileGuid as varchar(max)) from Pages
bsqldb:186: dbsqlsend(): OK
bsqldb:194: dbsqlok(): OK
bsqldb:289: calling dbresults: OK
Result set 1
Freeing prior allocations
Allocating buffers
Allocating compute buffers
Metadata
col     name                            source                          type             size    varies
------  ------------------------------  ------------------------------  ---------------  ------  ------
     1                                                                             text   64512       1

Data


Retrieving return status... none
11084 rows affected
Retrieving output parameters... none
bsqldb:615: dbresults() returned NO_MORE_RESULTS (2):
bsqldb:212: Query:
```

I'm using FreeTDS 0.64RC1, FreeBSD 8, and SQL Server 2008

Comment: You *are* running T-SQL from bsqldb . What does this query give in SQL Server Management Studio? And also without the concatenation `+ '/' +` ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the one of the values is NULL, so the whole expression concatenation is NULL.

You'd need this:

```
CAST(ISNULL(PageGuid, '') as varchar(max)) + ',' + 
CAST(ISNULL(TenantGuid, '') as varchar(max)) + '/' +
CAST(ISNULL(OriginalFileGuid, '') as varchar(max))
```

Comment: bsqldb doesn't seem to like your SQL: "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1
Server 'DEV-DB', Line 1
        Incorrect syntax near 'ISNULL'.
bsqldb: Msg 20018, Level 5
General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server.

bsqldb:191: dbsqlok() failed"

Comment: @David: this isn't standalone code...